# How to query task metadata endpoint v4 for memory usage stats?

Tags: docker, metadata, amazon-ecs

I cannot find a way to query my task metadata endpoint v4 to get the memory usage of my task in my dockerized ecs service. I have a hypothesis for a memory bug but want to validate it first by checking the memory usages when the task is running. Everytime I want to access the service from the ecs CLI I have an expired security token exception .I am also open to test it locally but even though the docker container runs locally I can't find a way to access its memory usage logs locally.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your problem related to how grab metadata info or is it related to how to get a shell in a fargate container?

Comment: I can't find a way to grab the metadata, I should be able to do this locally but I can't find a way with the ecs-local API